# FactoryGirl and getting an attribute-hash with all associations

Tags: testing, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, factory-bot

I have two related models – `Customer`, which has one `Address`. These are my factories:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :customer do
    address
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :address do
    company_name "MyString"
    …
  end
end
```

In my controller spec, I try to get a hash for a customer which includes the address attributes… which just doesn´t work for me.

The first try was to use `attributes_for(:customer)`, but that ignores any associations (as said in the documentation). After googling around I found the advice to use `FactoryGirl.build(:customer).attributes.symbolize_keys`, which should include association params. But not for me, I just get `{"id"=>…, "created_at"=>…, "updated_at"=>…}`. But `customer.address.attributes` outputs the correct hash, so the association seems to be correct.

So, I have a correct customer with a valid address and want to get a hash with all attributes, so I can test e. g. the creation of a customer in my controller spec.

```
post :create, {customer: !?!?!?}
```

Here are my models, for the sake of completion:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :address, foreign_key: :entity_id

  validates_presence_of :address
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer, foreign_key: :entity_id
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported in FactoryGirl. Have a look at this issue here: https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/issues/359

I think this is not a really big issue. Just write this:

```
FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:customer, address: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:address))
```

Comment: Finally green :-) I ended up with post :create, customer: attributes_for(:customer, address_attributes: attributes_for(:address))